# What is the difference between gravity="center" and textAlignment="center" and centralHorizontal="true"

Tags: android, layout

I have a question about Layout Arrangement in Android. Seems to me `gravity="center"` and `textAlignment="center"` do the same thing? How about `centralHorizontal="true"` ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:gravity

Comment: No unfortunately not. Have you ?

Comment: Wastes more time arguing about whether or not they should answer the question than they would have just answering the question...
The community should keep in mind that documentation is not always friendly to beginners; neither is googling information that's brand new to them.
We're supposed to be here to help.

Comment: What about `layout_gravity`?

Comment: @anomeric thanks man. I Appreciate that. Yes I am new to the Android world and to be honest google prohibits ips from my country to reach developer.google.com and I have to use a proxy so often I use android book sources rather than googles own documentation.

Comment: @cricket_007 layout_gravity is for arranging things outside the view, that is what I read on most Q&As here. Its like float in CSS

Comment: layout_gravity is akin to layout_centerHorizontal - it defines how a view should be placed relative to it's parent view.

Comment: Just making sure you knew that also existed

Comment: When I first started programming I asked a question on here about how to keep an int from going below 0 because I couldn't figure how to ask such a dumb question (a question I would consider far less informed than this one).  Not everyone on here needs to get answers to apache-link-O errors or understand branch prediction or super recursion, but everyone asking a question does need help.  Why spend 15 minutes bashing someone when you could spend 30 seconds answering the question and move on?

Comment: I think this is a valid question.  The answer can be very short but it can help other people looking for the information.  However, whether it has been asked already is another issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For practicality purposes, textAlignment and gravity are equivalent, except that textAlignment is a member of the View Class and the gravity is a member of TextView class.  layout_centerHorizontal defines how a view should be placed in relation to it's parent view, while the former two deal with how the view should lay out it's subviews.